# Trying to create a todo list with delete function

Tags: javascript

Im new to javascript and coding in general, I'm trying to make a simple to do list but cant get the delete button to delete all the checkboxes, it will only delete the first checkbox made. Thanks guys.

http://jsfiddle.net/fbct3oL7/1/

```
function taskadd() {
    taskNew = new objectTask();
}

function objectTask() {
    var task = document.getElementById('textinput').value;
    var listItem = document.createElement("li");
    listItem.id = task;
    var itemText = document.createTextNode(task);
    listItem.appendChild(itemText);
    var checkbox = document.createElement("input")
    checkbox.type = "checkbox";
    checkbox.name = task;
    checkbox.id = "checkbox";
    document.getElementById('place').appendChild(listItem);
    document.getElementById(task).insertBefore(checkbox, listItem.firstChild);
}

function deleteCheckBox() {
    while (document.getElementById('checkbox').checked === true) {
        var itemNode = document.getElementById(checkbox.name);
        itemNode.parentNode.removeChild(itemNode);
    }
}
```

Comment: check box id is repeating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified your code, eliminating unnecessary `id` and `name` attributes, and updated the `deleteCheckBox` function to cycle through all the `li` in the `ul`.

```js
function taskadd() {
    taskNew = new objectTask();
}

function objectTask() {
    var task = document.getElementById('textinput').value;
    var listItem = document.createElement("li");
    var checkbox = document.createElement("input")
    checkbox.type = "checkbox";
    listItem.appendChild(checkbox);
    var itemText = document.createTextNode(task);
    listItem.appendChild(itemText);
    document.getElementById('place').appendChild(listItem);
}

function deleteCheckBox() {
    var ul = document.getElementById('place');
    var li = ul.children;
    for (var i=0; i < li.length; i++) {
        while(li[i] && li[i].children[0].checked) {
            ul.removeChild(li[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="list">
    <input type='text' id='textinput' />
    <input type='button' onclick='taskadd()' value='Add to list' />
    <input type='button' onclick="deleteCheckBox()" value='Delete' />
    <ul id="place"></ul>
</div>
```

I also forked and updated your Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JohnnyEstilles/gtpdLkLq/.

Comment: Awesome man thanks. One more thing Im trying  to add a button to mark certain items important. I tried modifying things but can seem to get it going. Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/w2q4vkh3/1/

Comment: That's actually a separate question, but go ahead and try this [http://jsfiddle.net/JohnnyEstilles/pdLvearc/](http://jsfiddle.net/JohnnyEstilles/pdLvearc/). If you're going to be doing a lot of DOM manipulation, you should consider using a library such as jQuery, instead of pure JS.

Answer (score 0):

You give every checkbox the same id, and the getElementById method only returns the first matching element.

If you want to get all checkboxes and delete the checked ones you could start by doing like this. *(Please notice that this code is written freehand and untested)*

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(i=o; i < inputs.length; i++){
   if(inputs[i].type == "checkbox" && inputs[i].checked){
       inputs[i].parentNode.removeChild(inputs[i]);
   }
}
```

First get all element with the tag "input", then check if they are of checkbox type and checked.

Comment: Was going to +1 your answer, but you're suggestion suffers from three problems: (1) it orphans the `li` elements that wrap the deleted `input` elements, (2) it does not take into consideration the change in position of the remaining `input` elements as the checked `input` elements are deleted, when multiple `input` elements are flagged for deletion, and (3) it presumes there will be no other `input` elements of type `checkbox` on the page. And ... you have a typo `i=o` should be `i=0`. Sorry. :-(

Comment: @JohnnyEstilles your right on all those things. I focus to hard on the "remove all checked chekboxes" issue and overlooked the context. Your answer is the correct way to do it.

Comment: That's cool. You're answer is not bad. I just wanted to leave some "constructive criticism" to enlighten future viewers. :-)